# Why gradle automatically includes parent folder as a subproject when adding a subfolder as subproject

Tags: gradle

I have following simple setup:

**File structure**

```
$ tree
.
├── build.gradle
├── modules
│   ├── rest-model
│   └── rest-resource
└── settings.gradle
```

**File contents**

*settings.gradle*

```
def MODULES = 'modules'

file(MODULES).eachDir {
    include ":${MODULES}:${it.name}"
}
```

*build.gradle*

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        subprojects.each {
            println it.name
        }
    }
}
```

The task `hello` above will print out all subprojects. I was expecting only two subprojects: `rest-model` and `rest-resource`. However, I am getting three: `modules`, `rest-module`, and `rest-resource`. Here is gradle output:

```
$ gradle hello
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :hello
modules
rest-model
rest-resource


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

So, why does gradle automatically includes the parent folder modules as a subproject? Can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`includeFlat`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#includeFlat(java.lang.String[])) instead of [`include`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#include(java.lang.String[])):

```
def MODULES = 'modules'

file(MODULES).eachDir {
    includeFlat ":${MODULES}:${it.name}"
}
```